Yum and DNF commands return 'Killed' on Centos 9 stream server
I run a VPS server. CentOs 9 stream.
When I try to do anything with DNF or YUM commands, it always returns, 'Killed'.
For example, When I try run, 'dnf update'
it returns,
[root@centos-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-sfo3-01]# dnf update
Killed
[root@centos-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-sfo3-01]#
When I try to run, 'dnf install unzip'
it returns,
[root@centos-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-sfo3-01]# dnf install unzip
Killed
[root@centos-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-sfo3-01]#
I tried running, 'dnf clean all' command. But it did not fix the error.

I use Snap on my system to host LetsEncrypt. Is that the problem?

I have fixed it by increasing the swap memory to 2gb from 512mb.
